# Select items in List that match an interface

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following Interfaces defined:

```
public interface IStep 
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IStepBuildDataSet : IStep
{
    DataSet Data { get; set; }
}

public interface IStepBuildFile : IStep
{
    byte File { get; set; }
}
```

I have code that uses these interfaces:

```
public List<IStep> Steps { get; set; }

public void RunJob()
{
  // pseudo code, need to update:
  IStepBuildDataSet buildDataSet = Steps.Single(s => s is IStepBuildDataSet);
  IStepBuildFile buildFile = Steps.Single(s => s is IStepBuildFile);

  // call methods on Steps
}
```

What is the correct syntax for to replace the Pseudo Code? I want to get the step in the list that implements a certian interface. There will only be one of each in the list.

Comment: that code is correct you just need to typecast the result: `Steps.Single(s => s is IStepBuildDataSet) as IStepBuildDataSet`

Comment: Makes sense, it was returning an IStep. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: CSharpie's answer has the same effect but LINQier, I'd go with that one. It has the benefit of making the filter more explicit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use OfType to make it abit cleaner like this:

```
IStepBuildDataSet buildDataSet = Steps.OfType<IStepBuildDataSet>().Single();
IStepBuildFile buildFile = Steps.OfType<IStepBuildFile>().Single();
```

Notice, you dont need to cast the results, since OfType does that for you.

Comment: Nice approach, cleaner than my expression.

Comment: This is fantastic. I didn't even know OfType existed!

Answer (score 0):

You have list of IStep, so there could be more than one of different types of Istep objects in the list. so it's better to do it in the foreach loop.

```
foreach(IStepBuildDataSet buildDataSet in Steps.OfType<IStepBuildDataSet>())
{
    //do something here.

}

foreach(IStepBuildFile buildFile in Steps.OfType<IStepBuildFile>())
{
    //do something here.

}
```

Comment: The function Single() exists for a reason.